# Cannot store heroku credentials in container login

Tags: docker, macos, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to login to Heroku container with the command `heroku container:login` and I am encountering the following error:

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Post "http://ipc/registry/credstore-updated": dial unix backend.sock: connect: no such file or directory`
▸    Login failed with: 1
```

I was able to login successfully weeks ago, but I did an upgrade to my Mac and I am not sure if this changed the behavior.

I am running Docker version 4.13 on my Mac OS Ventura. Has anybody encountered any similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reset docker to its default factory configurations, then I udpated docker to 4.14.1 version and I ran `heroku container:login`.